eth_call late for one block
I am making a token sniper by simulating buying erc314 token

    def calculate_tax(self):
        try:
            self.client.eth.call({
            'nonce': self.client.eth.get_transaction_count(Web3.to_checksum_address(self.user.EVM_Address)),
            'to': Web3.to_checksum_address(self.token_contract),
            'value': Web3.to_wei(0.01,'ether'),
            'gas': 500000,
            'gasPrice': Web3.to_wei(3, 'gwei')
            },block_identifier="pending"
            )
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False

def run_task(self):
        start = datetime.now().timestamp()
        self.running = True

        while datetime.now().timestamp() - start < 60*30 and self.running:

            res = self.calculate_tax()
            if res:
                result = self.buy_token()

alought
i already use the pending for the block identifier,
the buy transection still late for one block like
enableTrading run in 7777 block
and buy transection is in 7778 block
is that the code issue or eth_call logic.
i am using it on bsc chain
any method for me to simulatin the transection as latest as possible

Could you explain a bit more what you are doing? I do not understand what you want to achieve? If you want to simply simulate your transaction on a specific block, add the block_identifier parameter to your call function: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.call

If it's a 3rd party RPC you are gonna lag. If have own, try geth.txpool for pending  and back run in mem pool.

@MaKa what do u mean back run in the mempool.I own a fullnode server,do i need to edit my geth client?like pick up the pending transection and run it and get the state and finally do the original call method?

@Neverwin Rather than wait for the change to show up from an eth_call on the contract, filter for the transaction going to the contract in geth.txpool: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.geth.html#gethtxpool-api, and launch your transaction with a little less priority than the one you are trying to land behind. If it's more delicate, can create a contract that you will call to perform the call and have it do some check that reverts if the first doesn't land.

@Maka Thx Bro,I done it by editing source code of geth client,i get the tx from tx_pool and make a temp state than pass it to doCall() function.I love u

@Neverwin Nice one, you sound like you are gonna be ok. All the best on your journey.
