How to solve Delay while calling contract method
I have a contract which has a trigger button and am calling that trigger on every 30 seconds so what i need is instant change in the contract as i have conditions to match and it is basically a time game so this needs to be very critical but when i doo the trigger call it reflects after a while but the txn hash is generated within 4-5seconds...
taking too much time to reflect any changes to the contract how to resolve that
 const maxPriorityFeePerGas = ethers.parseUnits('40', 'gwei');
    console.log("fees", maxPriorityFeePerGas)
    const gasEstimation = await contract.trigger.estimateGas(poolObj, timeMS, new_price, batchSize);
    console.log("Gas Estimation ", gasEstimation);
    const gasLimitWithBuffer = new BigNumber(gasEstimation.toString()).multipliedBy(5).toFixed(0);
    console.log("gasLimitWithBuffer", gasLimitWithBuffer);
    const maxFeePerGas = ethers.parseUnits('50', 'gwei');
    const triggerTx = await contract.trigger(poolObj, timeMS, new_price, batchSize, {
      gasLimit: gasLimitWithBuffer,
      nonce,
      maxPriorityFeePerGas,
      maxFeePerGas
    });

    console.log("Tx", triggerTx);
    triggerTx.wait() 


Can pay more gas to land on chain more quickly, try upping the priority fee by 2x or 4x. There is gonna be some max throughput on how quickly blocks get written. Can also see a discussion here for acting on a change before it occurs : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/163802/eth-call-late-for-one-block?noredirect=1#comment178261_163802
